# Cannot create circular shadow in Adobe Edge animate CC

Tags: jquery-animate, adobe, shadow

I am developing infographic timeline, in which circles act like a buttons. I want to create "pulsing" button effect using keyframed shadows of circular button(drawn in animate). It works fine, before I convert button into symbol to set hovering play/pause states. My circle occurs to be wrapped into square and I am getting square shadow. Is there any way to fix this problem?[Screenshot of a problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWZDp.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: wrap circle into div and convert this div into symbol